# Control the number of digits in html output of caret

Tags: r, knitr, r-caret

I have code

````
```{r comment=NA}
require(caret)
set.seed(42)
tc <- trainControl(method="cv")
m <- train(x=longley[,-ncol(longley)],
           y=longley[,ncol(longley)],
           method="pls")
m
```
````

which produces nice output in console

```
Partial Least Squares 

16 samples
 6 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  ncomp  RMSE   Rsquared  RMSE SD  Rsquared SD
  1      1.39   0.836     0.552    0.155      
  2      1.08   0.899     0.387    0.103      
  3      0.592  0.976     0.187    0.0183     

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was ncomp = 3.
```

But during html generation all numeric values are rounded

[image]

How to preserve the same output in html as in console?

**Further investigation and workaround**

I use RStudio. Just after starting R session `getOption("digits")` returns 7. But duting html generation numeric output is rounded. Console output is OK.
If I set `options(digits = 7)` in code chunk, then both html and console output become identical and correct.

I cannot understand such behaviour, but it works. Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Did you set `options(digits=)` anywhere in your `knitr` document?

Comment: No. This is full code which should be reproducible. Can you reproduce the same output in html? If I add line options(digits=3) it returns an error "invalid argument digits" during html generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem that I have not quite decided what to do with it yet. Chances are I'll stop changing the default number of digits in **knitr** (i.e. accept this [pull request](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/777)). Before that happens, you need to place `options(digits = 7)` in the beginning of your document.

Comment: @DrDom I have finally removed `options(digits = 4)` from knitr; the development version https://github.com/yihui/knitr will no longer reset the `digits` option.